# Best way to check a condition once in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

In React what is the best way to check a particular condition is met on the first button click, but only the first time the button is clicked.

The second time the button is clicked, the second condition is met.

I tried to do this with state, I set initial value:

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            itemChecked: null
        };
    }
}
```

Then on button click, state is set so on the second click the, the second condition is met:

```
 handleClick = () => {

    if (!this.state.itemChecked) {
        console.log('First condition met');
        this.setState({ itemChecked: true});
    } 

    else {
        console.log('Second condition met');
    }

}
```

Is this the right/best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, essentially, unless the function updates something else you can check against which makes the flag unneccessary. I would also initialise `itemChecked` as `false` rather than `null` to symbolise that it is a boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer to be the best for my scenario:

````
handleClick = () => {

    if (!this.state.itemChecked) {
        console.log('First condition met');
        this.setState({ itemChecked: true});
    } 

    else {
        console.log('Second condition met');
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like this:

```
 handleClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.firstCondition) {
        console.log('First condition met');
        return this.setState({ firstCondition: true});
    } 

    if (!this.state.secondCondition) {
        console.log('Second condition met');
        this.setState({ secondCondition: true });
    }
}
```

However if you don't need the side effects (the console.logs) then you can do it like this and it will give you the same behaviour:

```
 handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      firstCondition: true,
      secondCondition: this.state.firstCondition,
      thirdCondition: this.state.secondCondition,
      /** etc. **/
    });
}
```

Comment: Those two examples are _not_ functionally identical.

Comment: But they are literally not going to do the same thing. The first one flips firstCondition to true only when it was already false, and same for secondCondition. The second example will always set firstCondition to true, no matter its previous state, and secondCondidion is completely different, being set to whatever firstCondition was.

Comment: OP wanted to change each respective condition to true consecutively with each click. Both examples I posted do that. So click once, the first condition is true, click twice  the second condition is true etc. In the context of the code that Op has provided, both examples give the same result.

Comment: The first example doesn't do that though. It will set both firstCondition and secondCondition to true. The condition would need to be `!this.state.secondCondition && this.state.firstCondition`